# Deploy laravel using gitlab ci in VPS WITHOUT DOCKER

Tags: laravel, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Nowadays I'm interested in deploying my laravel application on my custom VPS using gitlab ci cd and I wanted to do it without docker. But every tutorial I find is using docker. I was searching for a sample of .gitlab.ci.yml that will cover my situation. 
P.S. I've already configured my vps for laravel.

Comment: You should figure out what steps to take for a manual deploy. Say git clone, composer install, npm install, npm run, copy .env etc. And make it into a script

Comment: I would recommend this tutorial: https://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/

Comment: Nick Surmanidze, thank you for your comment, but my question was  about .gitlab.ci.yml, but thank you for your post. I've already setup things in this tutorial

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally after some research in gitlab itself and trials, I figured it out. I used gitlab-runner which executes the jobs in `.gitlab-ci.yml` And wrote this yml file for the very beginning:

```
before_script:
  - echo "Before script"
  - cd /var/www/html/project
building:
  stage: build
  script:
    - git pull origin develop
    - composer install
    - cp .env.example .env
    - php artisan key:generate
    - php artisan migrate --seed
    - sudo chown -R my-user:www-data /var/www/html/project/
    - find /var/www/html/project -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
    - find /var/www/html/project -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
    - chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
    - chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
testing:
  stage: test
  script:
    - php ./vendor/bin/phpunit
deploying:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deployed"
```

If you have a better solution, you can write here.

Comment: This should be the official basic example. Love it!

Comment: What executer you have used while registering the new runner? There are many options like a shell, ssh, docker, etc. which once you have used.

Comment: @ShashankShah At that moment I used ssh executor. However, this is the first solution I had in mind then. Now I would use a very different approach to handle this.

Comment: Hi @ata thanks for the quick reply! I tried the same but I am getting the error "ERROR: Preparation failed: ssh command Connect() error: getting host key callback: open /root/.ssh/known_hosts: no such file or directory" I am not sure what to enter in Enter the path to the SSH identity file  in the last step of runner registration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76629361/trying-to-setup-cicd-using-laravel

Can you please check this question