# Trying to setup CICD using laravel

Tags: laravel, git, ssh, gitlab, cicd

> **Goal:- Achieve CICD working with Laravel**

I am using Gitlab where I am trying to set up the basic level of CI-CD.

I have simply created a sample project and its repository and cloned the project on the server.

At the root of the project, I have created the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and have coded something very basic.

```
  stages:
  - build
  - deploy
before_script:
  - echo "Before script"
  - cd /var/www/html/laravelcicd
building:
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo "In the script section"
deploying:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deployed!!"
```

Above script will do some really basic operations like printing the message just to ensure I am on the correct way of implementation.

I have installed the GitLab-runner over my ubuntu apache2 server and installed it successfully.

Initially, I fired the command

```
sudo gitlab-runner register
```

Enter the GitLab instance URL (for example, https://gitlab.com/): I have given my GitLab URL under the gitlab settings something like this

[image]

I have added all the needed information asked below.

```
Enter the registration token:
Enter a description for the runner:
Enter tags for the runner (comma-separated):
Enter optional maintenance note for the runner:
```

> **Registering runner... succeeded**

Now, it is asking for the executor

Enter an executor: custom, VirtualBox, docker+machine, Kubernetes, docker, docker-windows, parallels, shell, ssh, docker-autoscale, instance:

I choose SSH

Moving forward

Enter the SSH server address (for example, my.server.com): I have entered the IP address of my server.

Enter the SSH server port (for example, 22): Entered port number
Enter the SSH user (for example, root): The username of SSH (just like when I try to connect to the server.)
Enter the SSH password (for example, docker.io): I have entered the SSH password as well.

**Enter the path to the SSH identity file (for example, /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa):**

I left it blank as I have no idea what to do with this!

At last, I got the message

> Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's
> Running already the config should be automatically reloaded!

[image]

When I reviewed the pipeline menu I got it failed at the build section.

[image]

**Update 10th July 2023**
I have created `/root/.ssh/known_hosts`

Now I am getting the following error

[image]

Anyone is having any idea about this error? Am I doing something wrong at the last step of registering the runner?

Please help.

Comment: Have you added SSH public key to `known_hosts` file in your server? If you don't add that your server won't recognize the incoming ssh requests.

Comment: also check if you really have `/root/.ssh/known_hosts` file

Comment: Hi, @ata No, I checked the location but I could not find the .ssh folder under the root directory.

Comment: I have created the file under the root/.ssh/known_hosts and try to re-run the pipeline and got the following 

ERROR: Preparation failed: ssh command Connect() error: ssh Dial() error: ssh: handshake failed: knownhosts: key is unknown